# Como construir uma tabela classificatória?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, pdo

Estou precisando da ajuda dos amigos.

Criei uma tabela classificatória de times ordenada da maior para a menor pontuação.

Gostaria que houvesse a ordem classificatória com o 1º, 2º, 3º, etc... ao lado esquerdo dos times, de acordo com as pontuações.

Tipo, a maior pontuação em 1º, a segunda em 2º, a terceira em 3º e por ai em diante.

Mas não tenho ideia de como fazer.

Mas como há alterações nas pontuações no decorrer do campeonato, as posições se alternam.

Se alguém puder me dar uma ideia ou mesmo onde consigo descobrir como fazer, ficarei muitissimo agradecido!!!

Abaixo posto o aquivo que estou usando.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td align="center" width="120">Nome</td>
     <td align="center" width="120">Time</td>
     <td align="center" width="120">Pontuações</td>         
   </tr>

   <?php
      $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY pontos DESC");
      foreach ($sql as $res){
      echo '<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">

         <td width="350" align="left" style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold;">'.$res["name"].'</td>
         <td width="150" align="center"><img style="height:auto; width:50%; max-width:150px;border-radius: 10px;" src="'.$res["end_t_cartola"].'/'.$res["t_cartola"].'"/></td>
         <td align="center">'.$res["pontos"].'</td>
     </tr>';
     }

    ?>
</table>
```

No momento a tabela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostia que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acredito que terei que criar uma nova taela, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer as duas funcionarem juntas.

HELP amigo...rsrsrs...

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare uma variavel inteira antes do foreach, e dentro dele incremente-a. Então use a variavel no codigo html ao lado de cada linha impressa. Exemplo:

```
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td align="center" width="120">Nome</td>
         <td align="center" width="120">Time</td>
         <td align="center" width="120">Pontuações</td>         
       </tr>
    
       <?php
$order = 0;
          $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY pontos DESC");
          foreach ($sql as $res){
          order++;
          echo '<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">

           <td width="350" align="left" style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: 
          bold;">'.$order.'</td>

             <td width="350" align="left" style="font-size: 0.8em; font- 
           weight: bold;">'.$res["name"].'</td>

             <td width="150" align="center"><img style="height:auto; 
  width:50%; max-width:150px;border-radius: 10px;" src="'.$res["end_t_cartola"].'/'.$res["t_cartola"].'"/></td>

             <td align="center">'.$res["pontos"].'</td>
         </tr>';
         }
    
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: feito a devida correcao.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Alexandre Guerreiro, funcionou perfeito!!!